# Find general solution of ODE $2x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+x^3 - y^3 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find general solution of the first  order differential equation:
> $$2x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+x^3 - y^3 = 0$$

I have tried solving it by regular techniques for solving non-linear equations like separating variables or bringing it to exact form etc.
.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried entering it into Wolfram alpha?

Comment: Let $x=e^t$, $z=\frac1{\sqrt2}y$, so $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}=z^3-(\frac1{\sqrt2}e^t)^3$ is an [Abel differential equation of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind).